# Getting error when using JSTL in maven: DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have all dependencies added all this dependencies but still getting this error.Without using JSTL it is working fine

In jsp code using JSTL to fetch data

```
<sql:setDataSource var="myDS" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/survey" user="root" password="root" />
        <sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="${myDS}">
            SELECT * FROM surveydetail
        </sql:query>
```

In POM file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
          <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
          <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error is: This is error I am getting

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource 
 invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ${myDS}"
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.Dashboard_jsp._jspService(Dashboard_jsp.java:224)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ${myDS}"
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:285)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:168)
    org.apache.jsp.Dashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(Dashboard_jsp.java:280)
    org.apache.jsp.Dashboard_jsp._jspService(Dashboard_jsp.java:203)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issues. I managed to solve the problem by adding the exclusion to spring-jdbc in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```